# Webpack css-loader generate wrong image

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I paste svg to css loader across miniCssExtract and sass-loader(and offcourse i import it in main.js), and when i'm using url-function inside sass file i have generated 2 files(1 normal svg) and second with string `"export default __webpack_public_path__ + "3a93a0304bac6c9d74a5f25388ed6773.svg";"` that browser say can't read.

I waste for reaserch like 3 hours and i'm done, HELP ME!

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")


module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname,"src",),
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        main: "./main.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[filename][contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"),
        
    },
    
    
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template:'index.html',
            inject:"body",
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                  }
                  
            },
        

            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/i,
                use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader","sass-loader"],
                
            }
        ]
            
    }

}
```

main.js :

```
import "./styles.sass"
import BG from "./assets/images/BG.svg"
```

styles.sass :

```
// GENERAL START

*
    margin: 0 0
    padding: 0 0
    user-select: none

html,body
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    overflow: hidden
    box-sizing: border-box

// GENERAL END

// HEAD START
.header__
    background-image: url(./assets/images/BG.svg)


.head__head
    display: flex  

// HEAD END
```

Comment: You need to provide more specific details like how you insert it. Without any of your file content it is impossible to know where the problem is.

Comment: CSS usually needs the path from CSS itself to the image. It can't use relative path as you may be able to use it in HTML or Javascript.

Comment: now I used absolute path for url-function, and still in output in browser i get this background-image: url(b16484aa3810e1bbb3cc.svg);(cant-read)

Comment: I was using 'style-loader' on '.scss' files which also caused this issue, I changed to MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader and it went away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with file-loader.
There is an closed issue in css-loader regarding this problem
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/1358

Try using https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ instead.

In your case it should be enough to remove "file-loader".

Comment: so, i'll remove file-loader... and how i would use svg and other images?

Comment: Just import it as usual and have an 'asset/inline' for svg in config. Please see https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ for more details

Comment: Thank you saved my time!